# Error using convert2df function from bibliometrix package: Error in seq.default

Tags: r

I try to run these command which are from this:

```
library(bibliometrix)
# Loading txt or bib files into R environment
D <- readFiles("http://bibliometrix.org/datasets/joi.txt")

# Converting the loaded files into a R bibliographic dataframe
M <- convert2df(D, dbsource="isi",format="plaintext")
```

However I receive this error:

> Error in seq.default(iStart, iStop) : 'from' must be a finite number

How can I fix it from this reproducible example to continue?

(This example was taken from the package docs where it executed successfully: https://bibliometrix.org/documents/bibliometrix_Report.html)

Comment: Sorry for my previous wrong interpretation of your post.

Comment: I think this may be due to an error at the link. If you download the file `joi.txt` from https://www.bibliometrix.org/datasets/joi.zip and then run your code it executes as in the guide